# use data from excel file in another python script

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, vba

I want to write a python script that takes data from one excel file and uses this data and inputs it in another excel file to get the output. For eg, if i have input.csv, it takes the data from there, and replaces certain cells of output.csv and gets the value based of the calculation

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
Depth=data["Depth (D):"];
ID=data["Tubing inner diameter (dti):"];
API=data["Oil gravity (API):"];
oilvisc=data["Oil viscosity (cp):"];
```

this is the script i have currently, these are the inputs.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb=xlrd.open_workbook("hagedornbrowncorrelation.xls")
wb=copy(rb)
w_sheet=wb.get_sheet(0)
w_sheet.write(4,2,700)
wb.save("hagedornbrowncorrelation.xls")
```

the workbook "hagedornbrowncorrelation.xls" is my calculator, i am replacing the C5 with 700, but when i save it, all the macros and formulas in the workbook just go away and it becomes a useless workbook with numbers

Comment: i have a script which takes data from the csv, i dont know how to proceed

Comment: pandas, in my opinion, is not the best usage for a non-heavy data user. I suggest you try openpyxl instead.

Comment: @Longroadahead i didnt understand what you posted below, im a new learner in python, let me summarize it again, i am taking some numbers and an adding them to the hagedorn.xlsx file to do a calculation,but once i save it, it doesnt even work

Comment: So you are asking how to save a file with Marcos and formulas? I have edited my answers to take macro into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar project with openpyxl module which can be found here

> https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Because I build a UI with Tkinter, I did to open a file, you may not want to use a global variable like I did, this was a quick hack.

```
def getFilecurrent():
    global path
    # open dialog box to select file
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file")
```

Then you can store it using

```
ref_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("filevariable")
```

Then do your manipulation of the data by selecting the right cell using, also remember to select the right worksheet.

```
 weeklyengagement = ws['B18'].value
```

Afterwards, you create a new template for the file pasted into like

```
template = openpyxl.load_workbook("Section12Grades.xlsx") #Add file name
temp_sheet = template.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1") #Add Sheet name
```

Lastly, you copy the range and paste the range using loops. There are so many resources out there I'm not going to paste my code as it has some custom set up and it would only confuse you.

Edit: if you wish to save with Macro, you can do:

wb = load_workbook(filename='filename.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)

Formulas are string and if you wish to save the formulas, you have to keep it in the string format and save.